# Why did my xCode compiler output "lldb"?

Tags: c++

```
int x = 1;

int main()
{
    int N = 20;
    for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        float h = pow(10,-i);
        cout << h << endl;
        cout << r=(sqrt(x+h)-sqrt(x))/h; 
    }
    cout << 1/sqrt(2*x) << endl;
}
```

I have a program that's supposed to output numbers, such as:

```
0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc
```

but all it outputs is

```
lldb
```

What does lldb mean?

Comment: Where have you declared `N`?

Comment: How are you running it?  `lldb` is a debugger prompt.

Comment: What's N in your loop?

Comment: Sorry guys N is twenty

Comment: since you initialize `int i=1;`, `i<=0;`never will become true.

Comment: `N` is not `20` if it runs forever. SSCCE please.

Comment: @DonLarynx Post completely edited questions! We're quicker than you may think!

Comment: @Sofffia, it "runs forever" because OP doesn't know how to use the debugger, not because the *program* has any problem.

Comment: You are seriously asking for trouble by doing `sqrt` and division with `int`.

Comment: What do you use to compile and run this program?

Comment: @Cyber: No overload of [`sqrt()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) returns an integer.

Comment: @sharth I saw that, but I'm anticipating a follow-up "why is 1/2 producing 0?"

Comment: A copy-paste of your code works as anticipated on Ideone: http://ideone.com/yIE67r

Comment: @DonLarynx _"fixed."_ Nothing fixed as far I can see

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I used float instead of int.

Comment: @DonLarynx _" I used float instead of int."_ And what about `1/sqrt(2*x)`? shouldn't you rather use `1.0/sqrt(2.0*x)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, the former is fine. All the promotions will work correctly.

Comment: .. the fact the result is being assigned to an `int` is probably bad, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're probably running this program on a Mac using Xcode, since `lldb` is the default debugger on that kind of a setup.

If that's the case, just type 'run' and see what happens.  You might have better luck setting up a command-line environment to build and run your programs if you're a beginner.

Comment: I am doing all of this. See edit.

Comment: @DonLarynx I don't see any edit about that.

Comment: As in I am using a command-line environment

Comment: I opened a new project and it worked. Why

Comment: If you "opened a new project" it doesn't sound like you're using a command-line environment at all.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is correct, which probably means you are faililng to run it properly in your environment. I've copied your function and it works like a charm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int N = 20; 
    for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        double h = pow(10,-i);
        cout << h << endl;
    }   
}
```

Compiling it using console

```
$ g++ file.cpp
$ ./a.out

0.1
0.01
0.001
0.0001
1e-05
1e-06
1e-07
1e-08
1e-09
1e-10
1e-11
1e-12
1e-13
1e-14
1e-15
1e-16
1e-17
1e-18
1e-19
1e-20
```